# Proving three points are collinear.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry

[image]

Let $BCED$ be a quadrilateral.

1. $BE$ and $DC$ intersect at $G$,
2. $BD$ and $CE$ intersect at $A$,
3. $DE$ and $BC$ intersect at $F$,
4. $AG$ and $BC$ intersect at $H$,
5. $FG$ and $CE$ intersect at $I$,
6. $AF$ and $BE$ intersect ta $J$.

We need to prove that $H, I$ and $J$ are collinear. I can prove it using projective geometry:

*My solution*: Triangle $AGF$ and $BCE$ are perspective from the point $D$, and hence by Desargues' theorem, they are perspective from a line, i.e the points of intersection of their corresponding sides (w.r.t this perspectivity) will be collinear. Now from intersection 4, 5 and 6, we see that $H, I, J$ are indeed collinear.

But I rather want a **solution in Euclidean geometry**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Menelaus's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem),

$\frac{FJ}{JA}$$\frac{AH}{HG}$$\frac{GI}{IF}$

= $\frac{FE}{ED}$$\frac{DB}{BA}$ $\frac{AH}{HG}$ $\frac{GA}{AH}$$\frac{HC}{CF}$

= $\frac{EF}{ED}$$\frac{DB}{BA}$ $\frac{GA}{HG}$ $\frac{HC}{CF}$

= $\frac{EF}{ED}$$\frac{DB}{BA}$ $\frac{AD}{DB}$$\frac{BC}{CH}$ $\frac{HC}{CF}$

= $\frac{EF}{ED}$$\frac{AD}{BA}$$\frac{BC}{CF}$

= 1

Therefore, *H*, *I* and *J* are collinear.